# How to remove archlinux and install windows 10 back with bootable USB?

Tags: arch-linux, boot, windows, grub

I had my time with archlinux, enjoyed it, but I had a problem with the software unavailability.
I'm trying to install windows back, I used Etcher to create a bootable USB but it didn't worked. Grub just work it magic and USB never booted.
I tried [another method from this tutorial](https://onetransistor.blogspot.com/2014/09/make-bootable-windows-usb-from-ubuntu.html?m=1), no results.
I would really appreciate a help here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should start with a more stable and known linux distribution like Ubuntu.

Comment: Actually I had, and unfortunately didn't enjoyed the experience. I'm really fond of Windows and I don't know what got me to try Linux world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just erase `arch` partition during `windows 10` installation, but be careful, all the data inside the `arch` partition will disappear to.

If you already have `windows 10` installed in your computer, and you don't want to redo all the installation, you can boot with a live `ubuntu` cd, and use `os-uninstaller` ([here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller) is the tutorial) to remove any OS you want easily.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to make bootable usb I would suggest using [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.github.io/) to create Windows installation USB and just continue with normal installation (while installing windows you can reformat your HDD).

But remember to make backup for important files.

> Grub just work it magic and USB never booted.

For this you will need 
a) when starting PC press button (which button depends from pc manufacturer) to select boot device
b) in BIOS set USB as first priority (I would simply put all USB types and remove any HDD booting)

Comment: but UNetbootin official site don't mention anything about burning `windows` iso on a usb. I think it's only for linux iso's, however, I could be wrong

Comment: I guess it's not official, but still works. I usually follow this [link](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/create-bootable-windows-7-usb-drive.html). But now You got me thinking how I did it last time :D